# xen creating a new virtual machine with bridge networking

Tags: networking, centos, xen, bridge

I am using CentOS 6.5 64

use this [tutorial](http://wiki.xen.org/wiki/Network_Configuration_Examples_%28Xen_4.1+%29) to setup Bridge

```
[root@CentOS ~]# brctl show
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
xenbr0          8000.08002754b3fa       yes             eth0
```

create a new virtual machine (CentOS) using `xm` command and everything ok

**Xen configuration file**

```
kernel = "/var/lib/xen/images/vmlinuz"
ramdisk = "/var/lib/xen/images/initrd.img"
extra = "text ks=http://192.168.1.8/kickstart-minimal6-x86_64.cfg"
name = "xc63"
memory = "512"
disk = [ "file:/var/lib/xen/images/centos63.img,xvda,w","file:/var/lib/xen/images/centos63.swp,xvdb,w"]
vif = [ 'bridge=xenbr0' ]
vcpus = 1
on_reboot = "destroy"
on_crash = "destroy"
```

**after create**

```
[root@CentOS ~]# brctl show
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
xenbr0          8000.08002754b3fa       yes             eth0
                                                        vif6.0

[root@CentOS ~]# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:54:B3:FA
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe54:b3fa/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3884 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2832 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:310622 (303.3 KiB)  TX bytes:412047 (402.3 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)

vif6.0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr FE:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF
          inet6 addr: fe80::fcff:ffff:feff:ffff/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:18 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:32
          RX bytes:928 (928.0 b)  TX bytes:2192 (2.1 KiB)

xenbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:54:B3:FA
          inet addr:192.168.1.2  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe54:b3fa/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2935 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1403 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:188677 (184.2 KiB)  TX bytes:271882 (265.5 KiB)
```

**xm console xc63**

[image]
This mean that my bridge not working because vm can't call `192.168.1.8`

get the MAC address for `xc63`

```
[root@CentOS xen]# xl network-list xc63
Idx BE Mac Addr.         handle state evt-ch   tx-/rx-ring-ref BE-path
0   0  00:16:3e:21:f4:e1     0     4     10   768/769         /local/domain/0/backend/vif/3/0
```

and check DHCP status
[image]

xc63 get ip `192.168.1.118`

**ping**

from same host it working

```
[root@CentOS xen]# ping 192.168.1.118
PING 192.168.1.118 (192.168.1.118) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.118: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=2.28 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.118: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.907 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.118: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.724 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.118: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.809 ms
^C
--- 192.168.1.118 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3171ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.724/1.181/2.284/0.640 ms
```

from any device on local network `Request timed out`

```
C:\Users\motaz>ping 192.168.1.118

Pinging 192.168.1.118 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 192.168.1.118:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),
```

Any one who can give me an idea to solve this, i'll be grateful.

Comment: Following your description, `192.168.1.8` is on the local network, not on the host machine, right?  Have you enabled IP forwarding on the host machine?

Comment: I don't think the problem is in the bridge, are you sure that the configuration file's syntax is correct, or the file is reachable ?

Comment: @AndreasWiese yes `192.168.1.8` on local network, no I did not enable IP forwarding can you explain more ?

Comment: You dont need ip forwarding as the traffic good through the bridge. This is not routing.

Comment: Can you please post the output of iptables -L -v ?

Comment: stoped the iptables https://www.dropbox.com/s/qa1rrlyotubbk4t/Screenshot%202014-04-19%2014.04.39.png

Comment: please check update of the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all if you are using VirtualBox to host the XEN server please ensure to use Ethernet not Wireless network and set Promiscuous Mode to "Allow All".

Secondly just to make everything clean, let's start with clean installation of CentOS with XEN and install the Bridge Network and CentOS VM on it.

Assuming you have external server 192.168.1.6 with CentOS ISO extracted on /var/www/html/centos/6.3/os/i386/ and kickstart file on /var/www/html/centos/6.3/os/i386/ks.cfg 
and /var/www/html/centos/6.3/os/i386/repodata with correct names match names in repodata/TRANS.TBL file

On the XEN server (CentOS+XEN) install the following packages:

```
yum install -y rsync wget vim-enhanced openssh-clients
yum install -y libvirt python-virtinst libvirt-daemon-xen
yum install -y bridge-utils tunctl
```

Then edit ifcfg-* file to create the bridge, no need for NM_CONTROLLED=no in CentOS:

```
echo "DEVICE=br0
TYPE=Bridge
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
ONBOOT=yes" > /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-br0

echo "DEVICE=eth0
HWADDR=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
ONBOOT=yes
TYPE=Ethernet
IPV6INIT=no
USERCTL=no
BRIDGE=br0" >  /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
```

edit `HWADDR=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX` line to match your MAC address. 
Don't reboot on ssh console, use VBox console

```
reboot
```

after reboot, assuming you have DHCP server
the XEN server will got a new IP, login via VBox console to get the new IP

ifconfig result should be similar to

```
br0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:23:54:69  
          inet addr:192.168.1.105  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe23:5469/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:5063 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3142 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:34251267 (32.6 MiB)  TX bytes:361205 (352.7 KiB)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:23:54:69  
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe23:5469/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:149910 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5045 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:182020057 (173.5 MiB)  TX bytes:493792 (482.2 KiB)
```

Now the bridge is ready you can use the IP of br0 to get ssh console again

To create a virtual machine on XEN which use previous bridge:

```
cd /var/lib/xen/images/
```

Create virtual disk:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=centos_1.img bs=4K count=0 seek=1024K
qemu-img create -f raw centos_1.img 8G
```

Then use virt-install to create the VM:

```
virt-install -d -n TestVM1 -r 512 --vcpus=1 \
--bridge=br0 --disk /var/lib/xen/images/centos_1.img \
--nographics -p -l "http://192.168.1.6/centos/6.3/os/i386" \
--extra-args="text console=com1 utf8 console=hvc0 ks=http://192.168.1.6/centos/6.3/os/i386/ks.cfg"
```

Now the VM should start and be able to get IP from the DHCP server normally and able to complete unattended remote installation.

The ifconfig result on XEN should be similar to:

```
br0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:23:54:69  
          inet addr:192.168.1.105  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe23:5469/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:10247 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8090 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:102264338 (97.5 MiB)  TX bytes:827859 (808.4 KiB)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:23:54:69  
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe23:5469/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:998780 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:37992 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:724701715 (691.1 MiB)  TX bytes:2897912 (2.7 MiB)


vif5.0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr FE:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF  
          inet6 addr: fe80::fcff:ffff:feff:ffff/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:37 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:67 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:32 
          RX bytes:4381 (4.2 KiB)  TX bytes:9842 (9.6 KiB)
```

After the installation complete you can use xen console to get the IP of it, then you can have ssh console on it.

Answer (score 1):

1 - Check you can ping xc63 IP address from another host on network

2 - Check that the url works from other hosts on the same network.

3 - Check your web server logs. Or firewall rules

Comment: 1. how to get the ip of xc63 
2. the url working 100% from local nework

Comment: 3. log not change :(

Comment: please check update of the question

Comment: If DHCP is working then tour bridge setup is OK. You may have firewall rules involved... Maybe on the hypervisor. Check if you can ping 192.168.1.2 from xc63. And Check the output of iptables -nvL on the hypervisor.

Comment: xc63 not finish install i can't ssh to it. how to check the output of iptables -nvL plz help me I spend more than 20 hour on it

Comment: the result of `iptables -nvL` [image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kofn02pwuvcetni/Screenshot%202014-04-19%2022.54.33.png)

Comment: My advice is to check firewall on the hypervisor not on the xc63 host.

Comment: What about pinging the IP of xenbr0 from xc63

Comment: xc63 not finish install i can't ssh to it, I am sorry if I don't understand

Comment: i am using the local network to install OS on xc63